# Xamarin Android - Call JavaScript with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin

Using Xamarin Android (platform specific):

I am using a webview where I have no problem calling C# method from JavaScript. But I have a lot of problem calling JavaScript method from C#.

My HTML-file:
http://www.test.com/Index.aspx

JS-tag within Index.aspx:

```html
<script>function ReloadApp() {
    window.location.reload();
}</script>
```

I've tried following from my Xamarin Android:

```cs
webView.LoadUrl("javascript:ReloadApp();") – NO LUCK
```

```cs
webView.EvaluateJavascript("ReloadApp();", null);  – STILL NO LUCK
```

Comment: Have you tried sending the `window.location.reload();` directly like this? `webView.LoadUrl("javascript: window.location.reload();")`

Comment: What is your WebView type? Xamarin.Forms.WebView. if yes try using Eval - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Eval?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_WebView_Eval_System_String_

Comment: on its android.webkit.WebView

Comment: @andiblas, no it did not work.

Comment: While executing that `webView.LoadUrl` method, is there any relevant information being logged in the Output window from VS or in the Logcat? Have you enabled javascript in the WebView like this `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`? In this case that you're trying to reload the page, you may use WebView's [Reload method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#reload()).